# Hibernate (hbm) - refreshing set with where clause after merging the container object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, merge, hbm

I'm working with Hibernate 4.3.5, Java 1.6 and Spring 4.0.3.

I've mapped the entities through hbm, and I want my application works with logical deletion.
So, in each mapped entity, I've added a property named 'deleted', which indicates if an entity is deleted or not.

Because I don't want to load the deleted entities (the ones having true the deleted property), I've used the where clause in the mapped classes, so I only get the entities aren't logically deleted.

And also, I've added the same where clause to every one-to-many relationship.

In one particular case, I've got a Report entity that has a one-to-many relationship with the Document entity.

So, when I mark a Document as deleted, and I save the Report entity (with merge), I expect than the Report entity doesn't keep the Document marked as deleted. But this doesn't occur.

This is the hbm for the Report entity:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
     <class 
        name="es.entities.Report" 
        table="reports"
        dynamic-insert="false" 
        dynamic-update="false"
        where="deleted = 0">    

        <id name="id">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>   

        <property name="title"></property>  
        <property name="deleted"></property>                                

        <set 
            name="documents" 
            table="documents" 
            cascade="all"
            lazy="false"
            where="deleted=0">
            <key column="id_report"/>
            <one-to-many class="es.entities.Document"/>
        </set>                                                          
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here it is the hbm for the Document entity:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
     <class 
        name="es.entities.Document" 
        table="documents"
        dynamic-insert="false" 
        dynamic-update="false"
        where="deleted = 0">    

        <id name="id">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>   

        <property name="name"></property>
        <property name="type"></property>
        <property name="size"></property>   
        <property name="deleted"></property>                                        
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I use a Service (ReportService) to open a Spring transaction. The method is:

```
@Autowired
private ReportDao reportDao;

@Transactional
public Report save(Report report) {
    this.reportDao.save(report);
}
```

And this is the DAO (ReportDao) method I use to save the Report entity:

```
public Report save(Report report) {
    return (Report) this.currentSession().merge(report);
}
```

I put an example:
The parameter I send to the service contains a Report object, with two Document objects, one of them deleted and the other not.
The DAO method returns the same information, but I'd like this method returns only the documents are not deleted.

Note: if I use another method with another transaction, I obtain the report only with the document is not deleted, but I'd like to do this in the same transaction.

Can anybody help me or show me an alternate to this? It is possible to use other Session method than merge?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge  method create a copy from the passed entity object and return it. Try re-fetching the report entity post merge.

Comment: And can you tell me how should I re-fetch the report entity? Maybe with Hibernate.initialize()? Thanks

Comment: Add this method  and use it after you save report,public Report refresh(Report report) {
    return (Report) this.currentSession().refresh(report);
}